# Filtrar una lista de objetos con Angular usando checkbox y un rango de valoracion

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Este código no estaría funcionan como debería, devuelve la lista completa pero debería filtrarse por rango donde onFire y Promesa son boolean y un rango de valoraciones que la valoración es un nombre que representa el dinero a pagar de las figuritas
Esta bastante roto por varias pruebas que hice pero cualquier cosa que se pueda agregar o sacar estaría bien

A continuación dejo los componentes y el servicie:

**filtros.component.ts**

```
import { Figurita } from 'src/app/domain/figurita'
import { FiguritasService } from '../../service/figuritas.service'
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filtros',
  templateUrl: './filtros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filtros.component.css']
})
export class FiltrosComponent implements OnInit {
  

  @Input() filtroPromesa!: boolean
  @Input() filtroOnFire!: boolean
  @Input() filtroValoracion!: boolean
  @Input() filtroValorMin!: number
  @Input() filtroValorMax!: number

  @Output() listaCardsFiltradas = new EventEmitter<Figurita[]>()
  public filtro: string = "onFire"

  figuritas!: Figurita[]
  listaFiltrada: Figurita[] = []

  constructor(private figuritasService: FiguritasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.figuritas = this.figuritasService.getAllFiguritas()
    console.log(this.figuritas)
  }

  onFiltroChange(filtro: string){
    
    console.log(this.filtro)
    this.cambiarFiltro(filtro)
    console.log(this.filtro)
    //this.listaFiltrada = this.figuritas.filter(figus)
    console.log(this.listaFiltrada)
    console.log(this.figuritas)
    return this.listaCardsFiltradas.emit(this.listaFiltrada)
    
  } 

  onFireChange() {
    return this.figuritas.filter(figus => (figus.esOnFire() == this.filtroOnFire))
    
  }

  promesaChange() {
    return this.figuritas.filter(figus => (figus.jugadorPromesa() == this.filtroOnFire))
    
  }

  

  



  cambiarFiltro(filtro_ : string){
    this.filtro = filtro_
  }

  enviarFiltro(){
    return this.filtro
  }
}
```

**filtros.component.html**

```
<aside class="card_filtro">
  <div class="texto__titulo alineacion texto__fuente">Filtros</div>
  <form>
    <div class="texto__valoracion alineacion texto__fuente">
      Valoracion
    </div>
    <article class="input_container_filtro">
      <div class="input_filtro">
        <label class="texto__input texto__fuente_label" > Desde </label> 

       <input type="number" 
       placeholder="placeholder" 
       class="tamaño__input" 
       [(ngModel)]="filtroValorMin" 
       name="filtroscard" 
       (ngModelChange)="onFiltroChange($event)" 
       value = "valoracion"  /> 

      </div>
      <div class="input_filtro">
        <label class="texto__input texto__fuente_label" > Hasta</label>
         <input type="number" 
         placeholder="placeholder" 
         class="tamaño__input" 
         [(ngModel)]="filtroValorMax" 
         name="filtroscard" 
         (ngModelChange)="onFiltroChange($event)" 
         value = "valoracion" /> 
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="input__checkbox espacio_checkbox">
      <label class="texto__input texto__fuente_label">
        <input type="checkbox" 
        [(ngModel)]="filtroOnFire"
         name="filtroscard" 
         (ngModelChange)="onFiltroChange($event)" 
         id="onFire"
        /> 
        On Fire
      </label>
      <label class="texto__input texto__fuente_label">
        <input type="checkbox" 
        [(ngModel)]="filtroPromesa" 
        name="filtroscard"
         (ngModelChange)="onFiltroChange($event)"
         id="promesa"
          />
        Es Promesa
      </label>
    </article> 
  </form>
</aside>
```

**busquedaDeFigus.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Figurita } from 'src/app/domain/figurita'

import { FiguritasService } from 'src/app/service/figuritas.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-busquedaDeFigus',
  templateUrl: './busquedaDeFigus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./busquedaDeFigus.component.css', '../../container.css']
})

export class BusquedaDeFigusComponent implements OnInit {

  mostrarEstaCedidaPor!: boolean
  listaFigurita: Figurita[] = []
  texto!: string 
  filtroValoracion: boolean = true
  filtroPromesa : boolean = false
  filtroOnFire : boolean = false
  public filtro : string = ""
  listaFiltrada: Figurita[] = []

  constructor(private figuritaService: FiguritasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mostrarEstaCedidaPor = true
    this.listaFigurita = this.figuritaService.figuritas
    this.listaFiltrada= this.figuritaService.aplicarFiltroFigus(this.filtro,this.listaFigurita)
  }

  buscar(text: string): Figurita[]{
    return this.listaFigurita = this.figuritaService.buscarFigus(text)
  }

 

  aplicarFiltro(figus : Figurita[]){
    console.log(this.listaFigurita)
    console.log(this.listaFiltrada)
    this.listaFiltrada = figus
    console.log(this.listaFiltrada)
    //return this.listaFigurita = this.figuritaService.aplicarFiltroFigus(this.filtro,this.listaFigurita)
  }



  cambiarFiltro(filtro_ : string) {
    return this.filtro = filtro_
  }

  
}
```

**busquedaDeFigus.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-busqueda (busqueda)="buscar($event)"></app-busqueda>
<div class="container__principal">

  <app-filtros
    [filtroValoracion]="filtroValoracion"
    [filtroOnFire]="filtroOnFire"
    [filtroPromesa]="filtroPromesa"
    (listaCardsFiltradas)="aplicarFiltro($event)"> </app-filtros>
  
  <main class="container__card">
    <app-cards 
    [esCedidaPor]="mostrarEstaCedidaPor" 
    [figurita]="figurita" 
    *ngFor="let figurita of listaFiltrada" 
    [routerLink]="['/cardDetalle', figurita.id]"
    ></app-cards>         
  </main>
</div>
```

**figuritas.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Figurita, NivelDeImpresion } from '../domain/figurita'
import { Jugador } from '../domain/jugadores'
import { Confederacion, ConfederacionFutbol, Seleccion } from '../domain/seleccion'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FiguritasService {

  figurita_id: number
  figuritas: Figurita[]
  filtroValorMin!: number
  filtroValorMax!: number

  constructor() {
    this.figurita_id = 1
    this.figuritas = this.getAllFiguritas()
  }


  buscarFigus(texto: string): Figurita[] {
    return this.figuritas.filter(figus_ => {
      return figus_.jugador.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(texto) || figus_.jugador.apellido.toLowerCase().includes(texto)
    })
  }

  eliminarDeLaListaFiguritas(figurita: Figurita) {
       this.figuritas = this.figuritas.filter(
         (elemento) => elemento !== figurita
       )
       this.figuritas.pop()
     }
     
  filtroFigus(figuritas : Figurita[]): Figurita[] {

    figuritas = this.figuritas.filter(figus => { return (
        figus.onFire ||
        figus.jugadorPromesa() ||
        (figus.valoracionTotal() >= this.filtroValorMin &&
          figus.valoracionTotal() <= this.filtroValorMax))
    })

    return figuritas
  }

  

esOnfire(figus : Figurita[]) : Figurita[] {
  
    return figus.filter(figus =>  (figus.esOnFire()))
 
}


esPromesa(figus : Figurita[] ) : Figurita[] {

    return figus.filter(figus => { return (figus.jugadorPromesa())})
 
}

rangoValoracion(figus : Figurita[] ) : Figurita[] {

  return figus.filter(figus => { return ((figus.valoracionTotal() >= this.filtroValorMin &&
    figus.valoracionTotal() <= this.filtroValorMax))})

}


  getFigusPorId(id: number): Figurita | undefined{
    return this.figuritas.find(figus => figus.id == id)
  }

  getAllFiguritas(): Figurita[] {
    const figus: Figurita[] = [
      new Figurita(5, NivelDeImpresion.ALTO, true, new Jugador("Lionel", "Messi", new Date("1987/6/24"), 10, new Seleccion("Argentina", 3, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Conmebol)), new Date(2005, 8, 17), 1.75, 70, "Delantero", true, 6000000)),
      new Figurita(1, NivelDeImpresion.BAJO, false, new Jugador("Guillermo", "Ochoa", new Date("1985/6/24"), 13, new Seleccion("Mexico", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Concacaf)), new Date(2005, 12, 14), 1.85, 75, "Arquero", false, 200000)),
      new Figurita(4, NivelDeImpresion.MEDIO, true, new Jugador("Romelu", "Lukaku", new Date("1995/5/13"), 10, new Seleccion("Belgica", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Uefa)), new Date(2010, 3, 3), 1.90, 90, "Delantero", false, 4500000)),
      new Figurita(6, NivelDeImpresion.ALTO, false, new Jugador("Cristiano", "Ronaldo", new Date("1985/2/25"), 7, new Seleccion("Portugal", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Uefa)), new Date(2003, 8, 23), 1.87, 70, "Delantero", true, 5000000)),
      new Figurita(1, NivelDeImpresion.BAJO, false, new Jugador("Takefusa", "Kubo", new Date("2001/6/4"), 11, new Seleccion("Japon", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Afc)), new Date(2019, 6, 9), 1.73, 75, "Delantero", false, 200000)),
      new Figurita(4, NivelDeImpresion.MEDIO, true, new Jugador("Achraf", "Hakimi", new Date("1998/11/4"), 2, new Seleccion("Marruecos", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Caf)), new Date(2016, 11, 10), 1.81, 80, "Defensor", true, 2500000)),
      new Figurita(2, NivelDeImpresion.ALTO, true, new Jugador("Federico", "Valverde", new Date("1998/7/22"), 15, new Seleccion("Uruguay", 2, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Conmebol)), new Date(2017, 9, 6), 1.82, 80, "Mediocampista", true, 1500000)),
      new Figurita(2, NivelDeImpresion.MEDIO, false, new Jugador("Heung-min", "Son", new Date("1992/7/8"), 7, new Seleccion("Corea del Sur", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Afc)), new Date(2010, 12, 30), 1.84, 80, "Delantero", true, 8000000)),
      new Figurita(1, NivelDeImpresion.MEDIO, true, new Jugador("Keylor", "Navas", new Date("1986/12/15"), 13, new Seleccion("Costa Rica", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Concacaf)), new Date(2008, 11, 10), 1.85, 75, "Arquero", true, 200000)),
      new Figurita(7, NivelDeImpresion.MEDIO, true, new Jugador("Jude", "Bellingham", new Date("2003/6/29"), 13, new Seleccion("Inglaterra", 0, new Confederacion(ConfederacionFutbol.Uefa)), new Date(2022, 11, 10), 1.85, 75, "Volante", true, 700)),
    ]
    figus.map(figus => {
      figus.id = this.figurita_id++
      figus.imagen = `../../assets/${figus.id}.jpg`
      return figus
    }
    )
    return figus
  }

}
```

La idea de mi código es que teniendo una lista de la clase figuritas hacer que el siguiente input devuelva la lista filtrada quitándole los objetos a la lista y que devuelva solo los objetos que cumplen la condición, onFire = true, Promesa = true y los objetos que cumplan con el rango de  valoración entre un valor mínimo y máxima

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda